# UnrealIRCd or InspIRCd

Tags: irc

I am the manager of a small IRC server of 100-300 simultaneous connected users since now 8 years, I am under UnrealIRCd. I see many competitors replacing their UnrealIRCd by InspIRCd and I would like to understand why they do that?
What are the benefits of InspIRCd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can compare the two IRC servers, a good comparison could be found at [Comparison of Internet Relay Chat daemons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_daemons)

Few additions as well are:

- Both ircd projects are up to date.
- Both have a rich modules libraries.
- Both have a good recent commit history & issue tracker.
- They have **almost** the same feature support, although InspIRCD is in favor.

For me personally, i prefer InspIRCD, i feel they have the edge, with accepting new ideas and implementing features.

At the end, base on those comparison, it doesn't really matter, both of them are doing a great job all around, and are well distinguished between others.